# Middle div take up remaining width

Tags: html, css

I have next html structure :

```
<div class="offerButtons">
  <button type="reset" class="btnReset"><span> No </span></button>
  <input type="text" class="offerInput" />
  <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit"><span> Yes </span></button>
</div>
```

And my css is as follows :

```
.offerButtons {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.btnReset, .btnSubmit {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}

.btnReset span, .btnSubmit span{
   color: red;
}

.offerInput {
  height: 31px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

btnReset and btnSubmit have a fixed width. What I want is that those two buttons have fixed width and that the inout field takes the rest of the width.

I want to get something like :

[image]

But now, with this code, I get :

[image]

Any idea?

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5f561wy3/2/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use css3 [**`flexbox`**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as well. Following css will make it like you want:

```
.offerButtons {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
}
.offerInput {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```css
.offerButtons {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.btnReset, .btnSubmit {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btnReset span, .btnSubmit span{
  color: red;
}

.offerInput {
  height: 31px;
  text-indent: 15;
  margin: 0 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="offerButtons">
  <button type="reset" class="btnReset"><span> No </span></button>
  <input type="text" class="offerInput" />
  <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit"><span> Yes </span></button>
</div>
```

However if you are not comfortable with `flexbox` here is another method that will work in almost most of the browsers.

```css
.offerButtons {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.btnReset, .btnSubmit {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 3px;
  top: 50%;
}
.btnSubmit {
  left: auto;
  right: 3px;
}

.btnReset span, .btnSubmit span{
  color: red;
}

.offerInput {
  height: 31px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="offerButtons">
  <button type="reset" class="btnReset"><span> No </span></button>
  <input type="text" class="offerInput" />
  <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit"><span> Yes </span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: I know. With flexbox is easier, but IE makes problems with flexbox.

Comment: @Boky https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php It's worth remembering that support for IE is not as important as it once was :-)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I am very glad to hear that ;-) , but unfortunately for my boss is important :)

Comment: @Boky I understand that the clients who pay, they wants compatibility with each browser irrespective of browser share in market.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `css calc()function`, as below to minus the width of yes and no button from `.offerInput`.

```css
.offerButtons {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.btnReset, .btnSubmit {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}

.btnReset span, .btnSubmit span{
   color: red;
}

.offerInput {
  height: 31px;
  text-indent: 15;
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  width:calc(98% - 70px);
 }
```

```html
<div class="offerButtons">
  <button type="reset" class="btnReset"><span> No </span></button>
  <input type="text" class="offerInput" />
  <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit"><span> Yes </span></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend flexbox as a good option here. Just put flex on the parent div and set width of offerInput to 100% and you are good to go. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think flex grow will be necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a one line solution by setting custom width of input field by [calculating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) the widths of buttons:

```
.offerInput {
    height: 31px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    display: table-cell;
    width: calc(500px - 75px);
}
```

There're many other possible ways of doing this including adopting any front end framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Zurb Foundation](http://getbootstrap.com/) especially if you're designing a complete web view.

Comment: No need for a big framework for something like this.

Comment: @torazaburo Obviously, this is only suggested if someone is building a complete view. Including a framework is actually a suggestion for complete web design rather than exact answer to this minor UI issue. BTW thanks for pointing out, I've updated the answer